# LINQPad - Control column order when rendering IEnumerable<MyObject>?

Tags: linqpad

I've written a query that returns `IEnumerable<Item>`, where the `Item` class has several different members:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties;
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items;

    public Item(XElement itemElement)
    {
        Name = itemElement.Attribute("name").Value;
        Type = itemElement.Attribute("type").Value;
        Properties = from property in itemElement.Elements("Property")
                     select new Property(property);

        Items = from item in itemElement.Elements("Item")
                select new Item(item);
    }
}
```

I don't like the order that LINQPad has chosen for assigning the `Item` properties to columns in the result tables. I want the columns to appear in the order `Name`, `Type`, `Properties`, `Items`, but the LINQPad default is showing `Properties`, `Items`, `Name`, `Type`. Is there a way to hint to LINQPad what order the property columns should be in?

Comment: try adding `{get; set;}` to `Properties` and `Type` to make them properties - the code to generate the table may loop through fields first, then properties.  Or you could write a [custom visualizer](http://www.linqpad.net/customvisualizers.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would still like to know if 
>   there is a way to override the LINQPad Dump() column order in
>   situations where I don't control the declaration order for
>   `IEnumerable<FooObject>`.

Providing you can change you Item class, you can do this by implementing ICustomMemberProvider (see http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx#extensibility)

eg

```
public class Item : LINQPad.ICustomMemberProvider
{

    ...

    IEnumerable<string> ICustomMemberProvider.GetNames() 
    {
        return new [] { "Name", "Type", "Properties", "Items" };
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> ICustomMemberProvider.GetTypes ()
    {
        return new [] { typeof (string),  typeof(string) , typeof(IEnumerable<Item>), typeof(IEnumerable<Property>) };
    }

    IEnumerable<object> ICustomMemberProvider.GetValues ()
    {
        return new object [] { this.Name, this.Type, this.Properties, this.Items };
    }                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQPad sort order described in the question was occurring because Name and Type were C# object properties, but the Properties member and Items member were actually C# object fields.

It seems LINQPad displays object fields before properties by default.

I added auto-implemented properties to the Properties member and Items member:

```
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; private set; }
```

After making this change, the LINQPad column order matched the member declaration order in the class, which is what I originally wanted.

But, I will leave this question here and not accept my own answer, because I would still like to know if there is a way to override the LINQPad `Dump()` column order in situations where I don't control the declaration order for `IEnumerable<FooObject>`.